# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to install ruby on my docker container and I am following [this](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/1f19e5d966aadfaac7ce4a9d4db8f982db2fe690/2.3/Dockerfile) one to build the container. When I build for new image the error response

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgdbm-dev : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                    libc-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex     && buildDeps='      bison       libgdbm-dev         ruby    '   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  && curl -fSL -o ruby.tar.gz "http://cache.ruby-   lang.org/pub/ruby/$RUBY_MAJOR/ruby-$RUBY_VERSION.tar.gz"  && echo    "$RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256 *ruby.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -    && mkdir -p /usr/src/ruby   && tar -xzf ruby.tar.gz -C /usr/src/ruby --strip-components=1   && rm ruby.tar.gz   && cd /usr/src/ruby     && { echo '#define ENABLE_PATH_CHECK 0'; echo; cat file.c; } > file.c.new && mv file.c.new file.c   && autoconf     && ./configure --disable-install-doc    && make -j"$(nproc)"    && make install     && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps    && gem update --system $RUBYGEMS_VERSION    && rm -r /usr/src/ruby' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I have tried to install the packages by replacing **apt-get** with **aptitude** and seems like not working and producing some what same response. In addition to this I  have to use

> FROM tracer0tong/android-emulator

in the begining to install Android emulator . Is there any other way to install ruby along with the Android? All kinda helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official docker container [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) then if you got o github the dependencies are:

```
...
RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        bison \
        libgdbm-dev \
        ruby \
    ' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps \
...
```

check the complete [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/1f19e5d966aadfaac7ce4a9d4db8f982db2fe690/2.3/Dockerfile)

Comment: I have followed the same doc to implement here in my local. The portion you have pasted above is raising error I hope. I have tried the exact copy of the above mentioned Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement to have the latest version of ruby in container? If not, you can use the official package provided by ubuntu using apt-get. Here is the sample Dockerfile which installs ruby 1.9.3 on an ubuntu container.

```
ubuntu@xyz:~$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby-full
ubuntu@xyz:~$
```

Once you build the image, you can launch a container from it and check the ruby status.

```
ubuntu@xyz:~$ docker run -it 777b10ca8b7b /bin/bash
root@6d4a3f1d2031:/# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
root@6d4a3f1d2031:/#
```

**Update:-**

Looking at the Dockerfile of tracer0tong/android-emulator, it uses ubuntu12.04. You can use this to install ruby on the container:-

```
FROM tracer0tong/android-emulator
RUN apt-get -y install python-software-properties && apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng && apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby1.8 ruby1.9.3 ruby2.2
```

Comment: But I need to use the version 2.0 or it's higher , that is the problem here.

Comment: Can I specify the version of the ruby package here in this command "RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install ruby-full"

Comment: Try the above example with `apt-get install ruby2.2`. You can look at the updated part in answer, it mentions installation of version 2.2. Give it a try.

Comment: Ok. Let me have a try.